# Matching array elements to dictionary keys in Python

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I'm trying to match up elements in an array to dictionary keys.  More specifically, I have a dictionary whose keys identify a disease state (a set of 0s and 1s) and an age (0-100) (ie, ((0,1,1,0), 35) is a key).  I want to loop through these keys and get the corresponding values to put them in specific places in an array.  The array that I have is structured such that the first four columns represent the disease state (0,1,1,0) and the fifth column represents the age.  I want to have the sixth column be filled in with the information from the dictionary, given the corresponding disease state and age.  Here is an example of the structure:

```
# Inputs
dis_state_list = [(0,0,0,1), (0,1,0,1), (0,1, 0,1), (0,0,0,0)]
ages = np.array([5, 10, 15, 20])
sims = np.zeros([5, 6])
# Make dictionary
dis_age_dict = {}
for a in ages:
    for d in dis_state_list:
        dis_age_dict[tuple(d), a] = np.random.normal(loc = 0, scale = .1, size = 1) 

# Input sample values
sims[:, 4] = np.array([5, 10, 15, 15, 20])
sims [1,3] = 1
sims [2,1] = 1
```

To clarify, I want to fill in the last column of 'sims' with the items in the dictionary, based on the disease state and age of each sim.

Comment: Sorry for being ignorant ... What version of Python are you using and what is np?

Comment: @jc: those are good questions. for the latter: `np` is an oft-used abbreviation for [numpy](http://numpy.scipy.org/); e.g. `import numpy as np`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
>>> sims
array([[  0.,   0.,   0.,   1.,   5.,   0.],
       [  0.,   1.,   0.,   1.,  10.,   0.],
       [  0.,   1.,   0.,   1.,  15.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  20.,   0.]])
```

and

```
>>> d
{ ((0, 0, 0, 1), 5):  -1,
  ((0, 0, 0, 0), 20): -4,
  ((0, 1, 0, 1), 15): -3,
  ((0, 1, 0, 1), 10): -2 }
```

(not actual display format, just put that way for easier viewing)

Do the following

```
for row in sims:
    key = (tuple(row[:4]), row[4])

    row[5] = d[key]
```

And then you get

```
>>> sims
array([[  0.,   0.,   0.,   1.,   5.,  -1.],
       [  0.,   1.,   0.,   1.,  10.,  -2.],
       [  0.,   1.,   0.,   1.,  15.,  -3.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  20.,  -4.]])
```